# cxGrid - Footer summary of checked records

Tags: delphi, tcxgrid

In cxGrid,I have a column that is boolean (properties : checkbox).
How can I do a footer summary (SUM) of such a column i.e to sum how many records are checked.

Right now, if I set it to SUM, my footer summary displays negative numbers for the items checked.How can I avoid these negative numbers?

edit :
I have found a would be solution on their site with :

```
procedure TForm1.cxGrid1DBTableView1DataControllerSummaryFooterSummaryItemsSummary(
  ASender: TcxDataSummaryItems; Arguments: TcxSummaryEventArguments;
  var OutArguments: TcxSummaryEventOutArguments);
var
  si: TcxGridDBTableSummaryItem;
begin
  si := Arguments.SummaryItem as TcxGridDBTableSummaryItem;
  if si.Column = cxGrid1DBTableView1Sonda then
    OutArguments.Done := not OutArguments.Value;
end;
```

However I am getting the error :
Could not convert variant of type (Null) into  type (Boolean).

Dont understand this. Field is boolean type (bit).

edit2:

The problem is that sql server by default sets boolean type to NULL.
That is why the conversion error.

Comment: I'd ask [here](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/List/1).

Comment: Unfortunately there is no answer : https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/S136683

Comment: DevExpress always extensively updates their products and their support has greatly improved. That question you linked is 7 years old and migrated from their old support system. You should just ask it yourself again.

Comment: Regarding your edit: I guess you have to decide if you want `Null`s counted as checked or not and work with `VarIsNull` accordingly.

Comment: @Uli Gerhardt NULL should be unchecked.

Comment: OK, then I'd try handling it that way - probably using `VarIsNull`, as written above. :-)

Comment: What database do you use? what is type of that column in database?

Comment: @Uli Gerhardt  What should I write ?

Comment: @mikia this is sql server 2014.Column type is bit.

Answer (score 2):

You can also just set your grid to calculate that summary using a different field , for example a calculated field where you assign the exact value you want to add each time.

- Add a calculated field to your dataset, with the desired value.
  MyHiddenField.Value := -1 * YourCheckingField.AsInteger;
- Go to the Summaries Tab on the CxGrid dialog, and add a new Summary:

  1. Set the Column property to the Grid Column where you want it to appear
  2. Set the FieldName to your calculated field
  3. And finally set Kind to skSum

Answer (score 1):

It is better to send such questions to DevExpress support team.
You can customize footer:

- assign Kind=skNone to footer summary item
- use OnGetText event to show what you want

Quick example (shows number of chars in all records as footer value):

```
procedure TForm54.cxGrid1DBTableView1TcxGridDBDataControllerTcxDataSummaryFooterSummaryItems0GetText(
  Sender: TcxDataSummaryItem; const AValue: Variant; AIsFooter: Boolean;
  var AText: string);
var i,j: integer;
begin
  j := 0;
  for i := 0 to cxGrid1DBTableView1.DataController.RecordCount-1 do
    j := j + Length(String(cxGrid1DBTableView1.DataController.Values[i, cxGrid1DBTableView1c.Index]));
  AText := IntToStr(j);
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that you can resolve that problem in SQL component. Use typecasting and your cxGrid will work with Integer values.

```
SELECT CAS(Bit_Column AS int) AS Int_Column
FROM YourTable
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this :

```
procedure TForm1.cxGrid1DBTableView1DataControllerSummaryAfterSummary(
  ASender: TcxDataSummary);
var i, j, Imp:integer;
    Item: TcxGridDBTableSummaryItem;
begin
  DBTableView1.DataController.BeginLocate;
  for j:=0 to ASender.FooterSummaryItems.Count-1 do ASender.FooterSummaryValues[j]:=0;
  try
    for i:=0 to DBTableView1.DataController.RowCount-1 do
    begin
      if (DBTableView1.DataController.Values[i,cxGrid1DBTableView1Sonda.Index]<>null) then
        for j:=0 to ASender.FooterSummaryItems.Count-1 do
        begin
          Item:=TcxGridDBTableSummaryItem(ASender.FooterSummaryItems[j]);
          Imp:= DBTableView1.DataController.Values[i, cxGrid1DBTableView1Sonda.Index];
          if (Imp= 1) or ((Imp= 2) 
          then ASender.FooterSummaryValues[j]:= ASender.FooterSummaryValues[j]+1;
        end;
    end;
  finally
    DBTableView1.DataController.EndLocate;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
procedure cxGrid1DBTableView1DataControllerSummaryFooterSummaryItemsSummary(
  ASender: TcxDataSummaryItems; Arguments: TcxSummaryEventArguments;
  var OutArguments: TcxSummaryEventOutArguments);

    var
      AValue: Variant;
      AItem: TcxGridTableSummaryItem;
    begin
      AItem := TcxGridTableSummaryItem(Arguments.SummaryItem);

      // считаем проверенные
      if (AItem.Column = tvCompareisCorrect) and (AItem.Kind = skCount) and (AItem.Position = spFooter) then begin
        AValue := tvCompare.DataController.Values[ Arguments.RecordIndex, tvCompareisCorrect.Index];
        if not VarIsNull(AValue) then
          if not VarAsType(AValue, varBoolean) then Dec(OutArguments.CountValue);
      end;
```

Comment: This answer needs some explanation as to what you have changed and how this fixes the problem